# regex having a alphabet in a string

Tags: regex, vb.net

I was looking for a regex that can validate phone numbers, but somehow i cannot find a universal solution.

So i just want to check if the string has any alphabets that is a-z

If it does not then pass it, for example

000  -> Pass

000(1) -> Pass

000a   -> Fail

Comment: `/[a-zA-Z]/` <- this will help you

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: @Brian I think you mean [this](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: If you want it to fail with letters, the `/[^a-zA-Z]/`

Answer (score 2):

`(?mx)^(?=.*?([0-9]))((?![a-zA-Z]).)*$`

This will check to see if your line has any numbers in it while NOT having any alpha chars.  See the example [here](http://rubular.com/r/r03X1Ab0IN).

Answer (score 0):

its for  phone numbers validation

```
RegExp(/^[0-9 +()-]{3,30}$/i)
```

for only string

```
RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z]{1,2}$/i)
```